# expression must be a modifiable value

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to make a program using recursion to reverse a string but without using pointers, but it gives me an error saying it must be a modifiable value. What should I do ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char x[30],int start,int end)
{
  char c;
  if(start>=end)
    return;
  c=(x[30]+start);
  (x[30]+start)=(x[30]+end);
  (x[30]+end)=c;
}

int main (void)
{
  char st[30];
  printf("Enter the string ");
  gets(st);
  reverse(st,0,strlen(st)-1);
  puts(st);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line are you get the error on? Can you share its exact text?

Comment: `(x[30]+end);` syntax issues aside you really don't want to be going past the end of an array like this.

Comment: Try x[start] instead.

Comment: i have error with lines 11 and 12 @Mureinik

Comment: @TadrosEbrahim you never call `reverse` from within `reverse` so that will not recurse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these statements

```
c=(x[30]+start);
(x[30]+start)=(x[30]+end);
(x[30]+end)=c;
```

are wrong. Nevertheless the error occurs in the last two statements

```
(x[30]+start)=(x[30]+end);
(x[30]+end)=c;
```

For example evaluation of expression

```
x[30]+end
```

results in a temporary integer object. You may not assign temporary objects.

The function could be defined the following way

```
void reverse( char s[], size_t start, size_t end )
{
    if ( ( end - start ) > 1 )
    {
        char c = s[start];
        s[start++] = s[--end];
        s[end] = c;

        reverse( s, start, end );
    }
}
```

and called like

```
reverse( st, 0, strlen( st ) );
```

Comment: can you explain more what should i do ?